# AngularJS How could I disable ng-blur when ng-readonly is true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and encountered a problem when mixing ng-blur with ng-readonly. Even though ng-readonly is set to true, ng-blur still triggers (if click the input field then click elsewhere).

In the sample, ng-blur will still triggers to make increment to the counter.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cMQeVf2yJPG58CxS0eiB?p=preview

In app.js

```
$scope.counting = function(){
  $scope.count++;
}
```

In index.html

```
<input
ng-blur="counting()"
placeholder="sample"
ng-readonly="true"
>
```

**Question**
How could I disable ng-blur when ng-readonly condition is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use logical `&&` on `ng-blur` to call `counting()` only if `ng-readonly` is false

```
 <input ng-init="checked=true" 
        ng-blur="!checked && counting()" 
        placeholder="sample" 
        ng-readonly="checked">
```

Also, you may either set the value of `ng-readonly` using `ng-init`, or you can bind it to a checkbox.

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJwwKJ1raHmOqX5o19Qi?p=preview)